# Composer with BlueMix

Tags: php, composer-php, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use composer on BlueMix.

But I got following error , and cannot push completely.

```
2016-05-23T07:48:52.02+0900 [API/7]      OUT Updated app with guid 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209 ({"name"=>"zutsuyoho", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>128, "disk_quota"=>1024, "buildpack"=>"php_buildpack", "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
2016-05-23T07:48:58.46+0900 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2016-05-23T07:48:58.57+0900 [App/0]      ERR
2016-05-23T07:48:59.60+0900 [DEA/28]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209
2016-05-23T07:48:59.60+0900 [DEA/28]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209
2016-05-23T07:49:02.17+0900 [DEA/4]      OUT Got staging request for app with id 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209
2016-05-23T07:49:11.68+0900 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-05-23T07:49:11.73+0900 [STG/4]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (4.0K)
2016-05-23T07:49:12.07+0900 [STG/4]      OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (6.6M)
2016-05-23T07:49:12.37+0900 [STG/0]      OUT -------> Buildpack version 4.3.0
2016-05-23T07:49:12.43+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Installing HTTPD
2016-05-23T07:49:12.54+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [file:///var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/ee88f28c-4afb-47c3-bc0f-db9ddc1ebb1d_324f7c585bc6131bc3c80e2fe5d1433ecaa5cb4a/dependencies/https___pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com_concourse-binaries_httpd_httpd-2.4.17-linux-x64.tgz] to [/tmp]
2016-05-23T07:49:12.71+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Installing PHP
2016-05-23T07:49:12.71+0900 [STG/0]      OUT PHP 5.5.30
2016-05-23T07:49:13.10+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [file:///var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/ee88f28c-4afb-47c3-bc0f-db9ddc1ebb1d_324f7c585bc6131bc3c80e2fe5d1433ecaa5cb4a/dependencies/https___pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com_concourse-binaries_php_php-5.5.30-linux-x64-1444147920.tgz] to [/tmp]
2016-05-23T07:49:14.64+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [file:///var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/ee88f28c-4afb-47c3-bc0f-db9ddc1ebb1d_324f7c585bc6131bc3c80e2fe5d1433ecaa5cb4a/dependencies/https___pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com_concourse-binaries_php_php-5.5.30-linux-x64-1444147920.tgz] to [/tmp]
2016-05-23T07:49:15.97+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [file:///var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/ee88f28c-4afb-47c3-bc0f-db9ddc1ebb1d_324f7c585bc6131bc3c80e2fe5d1433ecaa5cb4a/dependencies/https___pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com_php_binaries_trusty_composer_1.0.0-alpha10_composer.phar] to [/tmp]
2016-05-23T07:49:16.11+0900 [STG/0]      ERR Loading composer repositories with package information
2016-05-23T07:49:16.11+0900 [STG/0]      ERR Installing dependencies from lock file
2016-05-23T07:49:16.12+0900 [STG/0]      ERR   - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
2016-05-23T07:49:16.13+0900 [STG/0]      ERR     Loading from cache
2016-05-23T07:49:16.17+0900 [STG/0]      ERR   - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.3.0)
2016-05-23T07:49:16.17+0900 [STG/0]      ERR     Loading from cache
2016-05-23T07:49:16.21+0900 [STG/0]      ERR   - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.2.0)
2016-05-23T07:49:16.22+0900 [STG/0]      ERR     Loading from cache
2016-05-23T07:49:16.26+0900 [STG/0]      ERR   - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.2.0)
2016-05-23T07:49:16.26+0900 [STG/0]      ERR     Loading from cache
2016-05-23T07:49:16.92+0900 [STG/0]      ERR Generating autoload files
2016-05-23T07:49:16.95+0900 [STG/0]      OUT Finished: [2016-05-22 22:49:16.951057]
2016-05-23T07:49:25.90+0900 [STG/4]      OUT -----> Uploading droplet (44M)
2016-05-23T07:49:35.79+0900 [DEA/4]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3bf58c10-8e50-4033-9293-fbb971236209
2016-05-23T07:49:47.70+0900 [App/0]      OUT 22:49:47 httpd   | [Sun May 22 22:49:47.698566 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 36:tid 140521759557440] AH00489: Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
2016-05-23T07:49:47.70+0900 [App/0]      OUT 22:49:47 httpd   | [Sun May 22 22:49:47.698760 2016] [mpm_event:info] [pid 36:tid 140521759557440] AH00490: Server built: Oct 15 2015 17:35:56
2016-05-23T07:49:47.70+0900 [App/0]      OUT 22:49:47 httpd   | [Sun May 22 22:49:47.698786 2016] [core:notice] [pid 36:tid 140521759557440] AH00094: Command line: '/app/httpd/bin/httpd -f /home/vcap/app/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -D FOREGROUND'
2016-05-23T07:49:47.70+0900 [App/0]      OUT 22:49:47 php-fpm | [22-May-2016 22:49:47] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 39
2016-05-23T07:49:47.70+0900 [App/0]      OUT 22:49:47 php-fpm | [22-May-2016 22:49:47] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

composer.json is here.

```
{
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
  }
}
```

After I pushed, App is stopped.
Vendor directory is not generated.

How do I use composer on BlueMix? 
Please help me.

Comment: you can follow this procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016039/cant-get-guzzle-working-in-my-laravel-app-on-bluemix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your log I don't see any meaningful error (the ERR flag is probably depending from the composer log printed on the standard error)

Composer is fully supported on bluemix and your composer.json seems correct.

I think that there are other meaningful log lines explaining why your application is not starting.

If you have these available and share, we could help you further.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added other log messages.

Comment: Your logs are showing that your application is starting correctly. Where do you see that your application is crashing then?

Comment: I saw application overview. for now I can see that my app is available. Another question, Where is vendor directory ?

Comment: I found app/lib/vendor , and I can use require 'vendor/autoload.php'. Thank you

Comment: The vendor path is usually used by composer to add external lib required. Nothing prevents you from using and filling it manually with your own library. It is usually at the root path of your application, but it may be different